# Determining a location's side of the road position with MapKit

Tags: ios7, mapkit, geocoding

Is there a way to use MapKit in iOS7 to not only get geocoding for an address, but determine what side of the road it is on?

I'm not trying to build a full function navigation app, but similar to navigation apps that tell you things like *"Your destination is in 100 feet on the right"*, I'd like to be able to obtain this information.

Does MapKit give one a way to do this? Do I need to adopt routing privileges to access such, or is this just not available in the SDK period?

If not available in the iOS7 SDK, knowing what options exist as services, would be a helpful pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not available in the SDK. You could look into something like an instance of [Project OSRM](http://project-osrm.org) to provide that info, or you could look into routing libraries from other parties.